# Heroku support for Sqlite and Postgres

Tags: heroku, sqlite

Why doesn't Heroku support sqlite3?
or
Why does Heroku only support PostgreSQL?

In case I am completely wrong and Heroku does support either MySQL or sqlite3 could you please tell me how? thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filesystem is read only, so sqlite3 wouldn't work.

Heroku itself only supports PostgreSQL, it's what they chose.   It doesn't make business sense to have to deal with tuning and supporting other RDBMS like MySQL.

There is an addons to use MySQL if you like:
https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb

You can also do MySQL via Amazon RDS
https://addons.heroku.com/amazon_rds